# Actionbar pull to refresh - options.headerLayout

Tags: android, gmail, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

The current Pull to refresh library by chrisbanes:

```
options.headerLayout = R.layout.actionbar_pull_header;
```

is not working, still PullToRefreshAttacher is using default header view..